# GWT RemoteServiceServlet Java 6

Tags: java, gwt

I need to deploy my `GWT` application to an `OC4J` server using Java 6.

I'm using GWT SDK 2.7.0 - according to the [release notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0) while Java 7 is the default, this can be overridden using `-sourceLevel 6` which in Eclipse I am adding as a compiler argument.

This has solved most of the problems the `OC4J` progress text gave me when deploying my `war` - but one seems to remain.

```
Operation failed with error: com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet : unsupported classversion 51.0
```

Ignoring the specificity of `OC4J`, why is the `RemoteServiceServlet` a Java 7 class, when I have set the GWT compiler to use Java 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't using the right version of GWT - either that isn't 2.7.0, or you are using the wrong jar:

```
$ javap -cp /Users/colin/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.7.0/gwt-servlet-2.7.0.jar -v com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet
Classfile jar:file:/Users/colin/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.7.0/gwt-servlet-2.7.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.class
  Last modified Nov 20, 2014; size 11978 bytes
  MD5 checksum ef76115d101d7321764ed74a7d8c1d62
  Compiled from "RemoteServiceServlet.java"
public class com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet extends com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet implements com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.SerializationPolicyProvider
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
...
```

I just checked gwt-user also, and it too is 50.0, check that your gwt-servlet is actually the version you think you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial on checking jars - it was indeed 51.0 in my project's lib folder for some reason (something I must have done wrong). I'll try and build again.